# How to select and delete at once in DB2 for the queue functionality

Tags: db2, queue

I am trying to implement simple table queue in DB2 database. What I need
is to select and delete the row in the table at once so the multiple clients will not get the same row from the queue twice. I was looking for similiar questions but they describes the solution for another database or describes quite complicated solutions. I only need to select and delete the row at once.

UPDATE: I found on the web db2 clause like this, which look exactly like what i need - the select from delete: example: 
SELECT * FROM OLD TABLE (DELETE FROM example  WHERE example_id = 1)

but I am wondering if this statement is atomic if the two concurent request don't get the same result or delete the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on [DB2 for z/OS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_selectvaluesdelete.htm) (Mainframe DB2) since version 9.1, or [Linux/Unix/Windows](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000875.html) (since at least 9.5, search for `data-change-table-reference`), you can use a `SELECT FROM DELETE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM OLD TABLE
  (DELETE FROM TAB1
   WHERE COL1 = 'asdf');
```

That would give you all the rows that were deleted.

**Edit:**  Ooops, just saw your edit about using this type of statement.  And as he said in the comment, two separate application getting the same row depends on your [Isolation Level](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_chooseisolationoption.htm#db2z_chooseisolationoption).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, ... FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = value 
     WITH RR USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS;
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = value;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but i am wondering what's happen if the application crash between select and delete. So the table will be lock for ever? or the table will be unlock immediatelly when the connection is lost?

Comment: @HPCS: It depends on the table locking level that was defined when the table was created.  Probably just the row or page would be locked.  Depending on the language you're using, an abend should trigger an automatic ROLLBACK of any database locks.